# External website content source rollup image in search results

Tags: search, crawl-external-content, rollup-image

We currently have a search content source that is pointing at our non-SharePoint website. The crawl is working fine and we are able to see results from this website in our internal SharePoint search results. My question is, for external content sources such as this website, will SharePoint search populate a rollup image field? And if so what might be the name of this field so I can display it in my search results?

When I use Google to search our website, it displays a nice thumbnail of the main page image next to the search results. I am hoping that SharePoint search might be indexing this image as well but so far I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's an image and not just an iFrame of the actual page? SharePoint does not thumbnail web pages (it does iframes). If you want it is very easy to implement a Display Template (like the site Display Template) that shows the iframe of the URL of the site. I have also implemented "thumbnailing" solutions in the past that equate a URL with an image and then assemble the result in a display template (but the image is not real time).

Comment: I should clarify that it is Google custom search not just the regular search. The thumbnail image it's displaying is not in an iframe, it's simply the primary (or only) image from the page that was indexed. My main question is whether SharePoint search makes any attempt to identify and index a web page's main image or any images on a (external) web page. And if so under what field name would it be under in the search index? If not, what sort of customization would be needed to achieve this?

Comment: No, not out of the box. Though it sounds like a good idea. You could easily do it as part of a Content Enrichment Service callout.